# Why i don't have Flutter icon with main.dart in Run ‘app’ line？

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OovPO.png)

I circled in the picture.

It is supposed to be as pictured below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl0jH.png)

Could anybody help me?

Comment: It seems as if you're in the wrong folder - Open the `flutter_maps` folder directly in Android Studio.